# Convert jQuery data to Backbone Model object

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a row (tr) which has my Backbone Model attributes stored in data()

Say this model is called MyCustomBackboneModel

Now in my details view, when I say

> $(this).closest('tr').data()

I get the object.

But I need to pass this to CustomModalView...So I do

```
new CustomModalView({
    model:  $(this).closest('tr').data()
})
```

In my CustomModalView, I have

```
this._initAndRenderModal(myModalTemplate, {
                model: this.model.toJSON()
}
```

My question is how do I pass the model from details view, mapping the data() returned to MyCustomBackboneModel ?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyCustomBackboneModel.set($(this).closest('tr').data())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data =  {
    someprop : $(this).closest('tr').data("someprop"),
    anotherProp : $(this).closest('tr').data("anotherProp"),
    thirdProp : false
}

new CustomModalView({
    model: new MyCustomBackboneModel(data);
})
```